# JQUERY: Resize div to window width

Tags: jquery

I am trying to force the width of a div to the width of a browser window. So that even if the window is resize the adjusts it's width.

I have been researching for about an hour and have found odd bits and pieces such as .resize() but can't find anything which works.

Comment: Can you paste some code so we can help you better?

Comment: what do you have so far? CSS fixes this with `width: 100%`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without a container limiting the width, a div should span the width of the browser window by default. You can explicitly set the width to 100%, but that shouldn't be necessary:

```
<div style="width:100%;">Hello world</div>
```

I think CSS is more appropriate here, but you can do this in jQuery like this:

```
$("#div1").width($(window).width());
```

To run the above code whenever the window is resized, you can do this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#div1").width($(window).width());
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtUWn/). For the sake of demonstration, the div expands on button click.

Comment: This works well thank you. But is there any way to changed the width as you resize the browser without refreshing?

Comment: Just added another example that should accomplish that.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I had attempted to use the .resize function but couldn't get it quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="full"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function reSize($target){
        $target.css('width', $(window).width()+'px');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('resize', reSize($('#full')));
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The code in my answer doesn't set it to 100%; it sets it to the window width. give it a try,

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I am adding the JS in an external JS file.

Comment: Can you include the code that contains the div you are working with and I can tailor the answer to fit.

Comment: `<ul id="navigation">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://hawkesbeaumont.blueplanetdns.com/section.php/11/1/leather-goods">Leather Goods</a>
<div class="sub-navigation" style="display: none;">
</div>
</li>
<li>
</li>
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</ul>`

Comment: This is the HTMl, I need the 'div class="sub-navigation"' to be set to 100% width of the browser

Comment: @Guy It doesn't matter how wide the DIV is if it's not displayed.

Comment: It is a drop down and does display when hovered over the parent <li>

Answer (score 1):

```
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

Optional:

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: The div is contained within a parent div which has a fixed width, so setting 100% width would only adjust it to the width of the parent div.

Comment: @Guy It's helpful if you mention important details like that in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can solve this using css width 100%

```
 div#full{ width:100%}
```

:)