# Dynamically resize div based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, resolution

I'm trying to optimise my website for different resolutions. In the center of the website I have a DIV that currently has a fixed size. I'm trying to make its size (and contents) change according to the size of the browser window. How do I do that?
This is my website if you want to take a look at its code:
http://www.briefeditions.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQUERY: Resize div to window width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095554/jquery-resize-div-to-window-width)

Comment: Any reason for not using CSS width property in % ?

Answer (score 10):

If you resize the page the div will resize with it and on load of the page.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('#div').width($(this).width());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       var windowHeight = $(window).height();
       $('#divID').css('min-height',windowHeight+'px');
});
```

## UPDATE

If you want that site will resize based on browser resize then use **%** instead of **px**

## CSS:

```
html {height:100%; overflow:hidden}
body {height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var width = $(window).width(); 
$("#divId").width(width);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need screen width and height for client(users) machine.

at onload of page  get screen width & height and set those values to divs using jquery/javascript

```
var userscreen_width,userscreen_height;
userscreen_width = screen.width;
userscreen_height = screen.height;
```

[check this for more info](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in your example iframe also has fixed size. You should also resize it to the parents width. In your example this would work:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('#content, #content > iframe').width($(this).width());
});
```

Keep in mind that you must remove all margins, as well as absolute positioning like: top, left, position:absolute from you element styles.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code from the provided link in question.

Change width to 80% in #content style.
And in .wrapper change width to 100%.

You have used mainly 920px for width, so whenever you will resize window the control will not re-size. Use equivalent % instead of 920px;